# Mixing dynamic/precompiled handlebar templates using assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

I'm using Grunt and Assemble to create precompiled templates on my site but I need to dynamically create some sections based on information stored in client-side storage.  Is there a way to exempt sections of a template from precompilation?

Comment: I think this might need a solution specific to handlebars and using a helper or something. If you find a solution, please post it. I'll see if we have anything in our handlebars-helpers lib that might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't do custom delimiters (a shortcoming of Handlebars), but there are a couple of solutions that might work for you. Neither is necessarily idiomatic, so you be the judge of how suitable these are for the project you're working on.

**string replacement**

You could use some custom (temporary) delimiters for the templates in the content that shouldn't be compiled, then create a block helper that will convert those delimiters back to valid handlebars expressions during compile time (I tested this for this answer and it works):

For example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("raw", function(options) {
  return options.fn(this).replace(/\[\[/g, '{{').replace(/\]\]/g, '}}');
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
{{#raw}}
  {{> foo }}
{{/raw}}
```

Inside `foo.hbs`, you might have something like this:

```
<title>[[title]]</title>
```

and it will render to:

```
<title>{{title}}</title>
```

This solution is hacky for sure, and you might have problems if you happen have any code examples embedded in the included content and one of the examples happens to have that syntax (like `[0,1,[foo, bar]]`.

**escaping**

This solution is most likely the better way to go. Handlebars will not evaluate any templates that are preceded by `\`. So you can do this:

```
<title>\{{title}}</title>
```

and it will render to:

```
<title>{{title}}</title>
```

The first suggestion probably wasn't even worth adding, but hey, you never know right?

Comment: This works well. Just follow http://assemble.io/docs/Custom-Helpers.html and http://assemble.io/docs/options-helpers.html to install the helper for Assemble. Thanks.